# How comment lines in XML file using Batch file?

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have a file context.xml which contains following..

```
<import resource="beans.xml"/>
```

I need to comment this line as follows using batch file.. Please help.. Thanks in advance..

```
<!--import resource="beans.xml"/-->
```

I tried this.. But its not working..

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "search= <import resource="beans.xml"/> "
set "replace= <!--import resource="beans.xml"/--> "

set "textFile=context.xml"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Does this processing need to be XML aware? E.g. does it also need to find e.g. `<a:import otherAttribute="abc" resource="beans.xml"></a:import>` where `a` is set to the same default namespace that is in effect for your given example? Could `import` have content, and how should that be dealt with? If your answers are that it does need to be XML aware, you should be looking to use a proper XML processor for this.

Answer (score 0):

check the [replacer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat) :

```
call replacer.bat e?content.xml "<import resource=\u0022beans.xml\u0022/>" "<!--import resource=\u0022beans.xml\u0022/-->"
```

as you have quotes in the strings you want to replace you need `e?` before the file name which will evaluate the special symbols.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But think if there are multiple import statements in xml file as follows..

<import resource="beansqqq.xml"/>
<import resource="beans44.xml"/>
<import resource="beans111.xml"/>
<import resource="beans.xml"/> ..
I want to comment only beans.xml line.. how can i do that?

Comment: @Allabakash - have you tested this? it will replace only `<import resource="beans.xml"/>` everywhere it is found. `beans44` and `beans111` wont be touched.